# Keras/Theano - how to multiply by vector in Lambda layer

Tags: python, nlp, neural-network, theano, keras

I'm trying to implement a lambda layer, where the function performed by the lambda layer is performing `transpose(P)*x`, where `x` is an array with `M` rows and each entry of `P` is `1/M`.

The issue I'm running into is that I can't figure out how to create a static array with each entry of `P` set to `1/M`. I know I can get `M` using the `shape()` function defined for theano tensors, but I'm not sure how to then create the vector.

Answer (score 2):

I think you are over-complicating things. If you want to multiply with a matrix filled with constants, you can simply divide by a scalar which is then broadcasted over your input matrix, e.g.

```
Lambda(lambda x: x / M)
```

where `M` can be defined as

```
from keras import backend as K
M = K.shape(x)[0]
```

giving

```
Lambda(lambda x: x / K.shape(M)[0])
```